# In Highcharts, is there a minimum value for text fontSize?

Tags: highcharts

I was trying to change the fontSize of legend item to make the text smaller. But with the `itemStyle.fontSize` set down to 12px (or 10 maybe), the actual text being renderer doesn't get size down any more. I'm wondering is there a lower limit for the text fontSize? Is there way to break the limit? I just wantted to make the text size even smaller.

this is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kHzr9/

Comment: what text r u talking about, the title the legend???

Comment: I'm talking about the text of both the legend title and the legend items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't encounter your aforementioned problem. Referring to this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wiltsc/kHzr9/189/), what I did was updating `35pt Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif` to `Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif` and font size is working fine.

Edited:
This is the effect of setting `fontSize` to `2px`;

[image]

Comment: if you change the value of `legend.itemStyle.fontSize` from `"10px"` to `"6px"`, you will see the legend items don't get smaller text size.

Comment: @Feedfedfat It did get smaller. Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/wiltsc/kHzr9/190/ I'm not sure what problem you are encountering. Please ammend my jsfiddle and we start from there.

Comment: @Feedfedfat Checked my edited answer for the '2px' effect.

Comment: Hi Wilts, you are right, seems it's only happening on my PC chrome browser, even IE does it right. My chrome's up to date though, this is really weird. Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: @Feedfedfat Mark this as answer if it did help you. Welcomed.